# which would be the correct way to toggle this boolean prop in Vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend

So I'm quite new with vue, currently working with Vue3 + TypeScript. I was told to make an input validation on an email required field, I used the pattern property from the  element and fire a disable class from CSS:

```
input:invalid ~ .triggerError {
  display: block;}
```

which enables a span with a message if the pattern is not correct.
I have one problem, I want to fire this message after onBlur event, so I'm basically toggling a boolean value which is a local component Prop.
Here's the code:

```
<input
  class="appearance-none bg-transparent border-disabled rounded-lg w-full py-3 px-4 col-span-2 text-secondary focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-pink focus:ring-0"
  type="email"
  :placeholder="t('contact.email')"
  v-model="email"
  @blur="focused = !focused"
  required
  pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$"
/>
<span v-if="focused" class="triggerError">
  It should be a valid email address!
</span>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
  import axios from 'axios'
  import { useReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3'
  import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'Form',
    props: {
      focused: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      }
    },

<style>
  .triggerError {
    color: red;
    display: none;
  }

  input:invalid[focused='true'] ~ .triggerError {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

[image]

```
error: (property) focused: any
Cannot assign to 'focused' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)
Unexpected mutation of "focused" prop.eslintvue/no-mutating-props
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message is saying: you cannot change the state of the prop, the prop state is handled by the parent. If you want to have a 'normal' reactive variable local to the scope of the current component, just use `data` e.g.:

```
  <input
                class="appearance-none bg-transparent border-disabled rounded-lg w-full py-3 px-4 col-span-2 text-secondary focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-pink focus:ring-0"
                type="email"
                :placeholder="t('contact.email')"
                v-model="email"
                @blur="focused = !focused"
                required
                pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$"
              />
              <span v-if="focused" class="triggerError"
                >It should be a valid email address!</span
              >

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Form',
  data() {
    return {
      focused: true
    }
  },

<style>
.triggerError {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

input:invalid[focused='true'] ~ .triggerError {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

Then you can change the state of the reactive variable `focused`